# Asymptote when function has a parameter

Tags: real-analysis, graphing-functions

I'm trying to graph a function that has a parameter $a$ with the help of its first derivative.

$$f(x) = x * \sqrt{\frac{x+a}{x-a}} \qquad a>0$$

I've managed to determine domain, derivative, stationary points and intervals where the function is falling and rising. I've calculated the asymptote and determined it to be

$$ y = x + a$$

The only thing left to do is to see in which point does the function cross its asymptote.

$$ x + a = x * \sqrt{\frac{x+a}{x-a}} $$

From this it follows that $a = 0$. I don't know how to interpret this result, or what does it mean for the graph. I've checked in $Mathematica$ and it appears the point where graph touches the asymptote is in $-a$. I don't quite understand that conclusion.

[image: Graph of function f(x)]

Comment: Well, in the slider you set `a=2` and so, you have the equation $f(x)=x\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x-2}}$, it's obvious that $f(-2)=0$.

Comment: @taritgoswami I've plugged in different values for $a$ and it does behave as $f(-a) = 0$ ($Mathematica$ confirms it). But I'm still confused about the equation with asymptote. Surely plugging random values isn't a proof, is it?

Comment: @taritgoswami Ah, I've looked at the equation again and made a grave error. The equation has two solutions, but only one is acceptable. I've overlooked the second one and it gives $x = -a$. I believe this is the argument that I've failed to make. Thank you for all your help.